# Web services data is coming late and table view is empty

Tags: ios, json, web-services, uitableview

I am new to ios sdk, working on app which includes web service calling and parsing JSOn.i have two view controllers on first view i am calling web service on button click and in second view i have to display all record in table view. everything working well , parsing values are also coming  properly. but values are coming late and table is displaying empty values. but when i am navigating back and coming again then it will display all button.How to handle this situation?

Comment: just reload the tableview and check.

Comment: Are you doing the call `Asynchronously` or `Synchronously`? If doing it `Asynchronously` your app will continue to work as it will not be doing the call on the main thread which the UI runs on (I suspect this is what you are doing) Whilst `Synchronously` runs on the main thread so the UI will not update until the data has returned. Which are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of Asynchronous download is making things ready for us in other than main thread. All UI components gets updated by Application main thread, In your case TableView UI updating on main thread and downloading happening in separately. I guess  only thing you might missed here is, after downloading finished not getting the notification. Once you arrange  notification after  downloading process finished, just update  your tableView by calling `[tableviewobject reload];`. Which ll done all reloading  of the tableview(this is nothing but refreshing all tableview again). Good luck.

Comment: -yes this is ok but first time values cell data is null. how we can reload table at first time

Answer (score 0):

Are you reloading the table view once the data has been downloaded? 
Something like this in your Table view controller:

[self.tableView reload];

Comment: yes this is ok but first time values cell data is null. how we can reload table at first time